# updating/refreshing in html dynamically after ajax success without page reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, refresh

### Heading

i have an updates section which is loaded first when the page is called, then a timed js function would again look for updates, i obtained the updates in an array object;  my problem starts here - how to refresh html dynamically, like if I receive 5 updates, then i want to create 5 cards to display those and currently i have only two cards.

```
<c:forEach items="${updates['updates']}" var="update" varStatus="loopCounter">
<div class="list-group-item media-list">
    <div class="media-body">
        <div class="admin-cont">
        <p>${update.title}</p>
        <p>${update.field1}</p> <p>Designation-${update.field2}</p>
            <p>
                ${update.content}
            </p>
        </div>      
    </div>
</div>
</c:forEach>


<script>
function getUpdates(){          
    $.ajax({
        url : URL,
        type : type,
        data : dataObj,
        success : function(data) {          
            //do something here to refresh and set data in html
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

Comment: @Nitro.de appending to `document` makes very little sense

Comment: @charlietfl you're right of course. We got not enough code to give OP an very good example I guess.

Comment: @Nitro.de that doesn't mean providing code that certainly is useless helps anyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the success function of your ajax call, you can do somthing like:

```
$('admin-cont').append(data);
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/append/

If you want to clear the `div` before inserting new data you can do:

```
$('admin-cont').empty();
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/empty/

Comment: thanks @david,it works like a charm and sorry for late reply

Answer (score 1):

You have to build you html code in ajax success. 'data' is what you get from ajax call.

```
success : function(data) {          
            $('#yourDiv').append('whatever you want'); //For example
        }
```

You can loop it and draw as many cards you get from ajax response.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, if this answer is too late but thought I should mention it anyway for others who land across this issue.

**1st Step:** Create a function 'UpdatePage' script, skip this step if you have your own update script. Assuming this is called inside when page is loaded. (Works if '$(document).ready(function()' is called)

**2nd Step:** Add an Event Listener to clear the timer after hash change otherwise you will land into race condition depending if you have a single page template with Angularjs.

**3rd Step:** Calling 'onGetObjSuccess' function inside Ajax(success) function, will only work when ajax is successful.

**4th Step:** Finally calling the last function where your data gets updated, NOTE: '.append()' will keep adding data to your html element but not remove it. '.replaceWith()' will replace the old data with new data automatically/dynamically.

Try it!

```
<script>
function updatePage() {
  // Calling Ajax function as soon page is loaded
  window.setTimeout(getUpdates, 200); 
  var interval = window.setTimeout(updatePage, 5000);
  // Use your update function here ^ instead or simply call:
  // yourUpdateScript();

  window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
   //clears timer when navigating to pages
    window.clearTimeout(interval);
    console.log('#Hash change detected & Timer Cleared!!!');
  }
}
// Call again to create a loop - update page every 5 seconds
window.setTimeout(updatePage, 200);


function getUpdates(){
 var URL = 'https://example.com';       
  $.ajax({
      method: 'GET',
      async: true,
      url : URL, // Your url, for eg: https://example.com
      dataType : 'json', // if format of the file type is in json
      data : 'dataObj',
      success : onGetObjSuccess,
      error: function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    }
  });
}


function onGetObjSuccess(data) {
  //Do something here to refresh and set data in html
  // This replaces old data with new one dynamically.
  $('#yourDiv_id').replaceWith(data);
  console.log(data);
}
</script>
```